# (PostGIS) Merge two tables based on multlinestring geometry

Tags: postgis, pgadmin, qgis

I'm completely new to PostGIS (and databases in general), so apologies if I use terms incorrectly.

I have two tables with multilinestring geometries, and I want to copy one field from one table to the other based on geometries. The geometries don't overlap, so I want to find the closest geometry. I've tried googling, and have found lots of ways of trying it (ST_DISTANCE, etc), but the queries always return wrong results (after checking them on the map).

e.g.

TABLE1 has the field to be copied, TABLE2 does not. I want to go through all records in TABLE2 and find it's closest record in TABLE1, then copy a field across.

Sorry if my description isn't clear, I'm finding hard to put it into a clear sentence (which makes googling it hard). I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help with this, or at least point me in the right direction. Ideally I want a SELECT statement to check the results, then an INSERT (or similar) to update the table, or possibly create a third 'joined' table.

I've been using PGAdmin, and QGIS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a third joined table using something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE joined_table (id1 int, id2 int) AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON(table1.id)  table1.id, 
table2.id
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id <> table2.id 
ORDER BY  table1.id, ST_Distance(table1.the_geom,table2.the_geom)
```

If it seems too slow, you can restrict the results adding this

```
AND ST_DWithin(table1.the_geom, table2.the_geom, 300)
```

to the where condition.

You can find a better description of the solution here
http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor

and similar questions on stackoverflow here
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/postgis-assign-id-of-point-in-layer-a-to-closest-point-in-layer-b

and here
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155373/postgis-nearest-point-with-lateral-join-in-postgresql-9-3

Comment: Thanks for the help Francesco. Turns out my issue was due to incorrect SRID's, that were being overridden by the correct CRS is QGIS. But since the above answers my question, I'll mark it as answered.